# How do I keep my MBP's screen on?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I have an early 2011 MBP running Lion. Is there a way to let screen not switch off  i.e, a keep screen on software? I heard several recommendations of a application named coffee for Mac but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I think you want [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/), not Coffee.

Comment: hey that's right, thank you very much, I am not sure now what to do with this post, can you post it as answer and I will mark it , or should I just delete this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the commenter said, [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) is what you want.

Comment: most brilliant app ever!

Answer (score 0):

#### Disable display sleep and screen saver in System Preferences

[image]

---

#### [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)

[image]